# How do I specify the User's LocalAppDataFolder in a VS 2008 setup project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, deployment, environment-variables, setup-project

Basically I am looking for a way to create application data files during setup inside the folder corresponding to:

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`

or put another way (for WindowsXP):

C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Local Settings\Application Data

I tried the solution suggested [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/34021297/how-to-create-a-folder-in.aspx), but id didn't do the trick.